# Writing a line of words into a 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, 2d, getchar

I'm trying to write a function in C that acts like a command prompt. I'm getting a segfault error. My logic of this follows as:
getchar() and check if its a space or not. If it's not a space, add the char onto the msg. If it is a space, end the word and add it onto the command array, and get next word. When it gets new line, it ends.

```
void getCommand(char *command[10]){
char *msg = "";  //Creates ptr
char c;
int length = 0;
while(getchar() != '\n'){   //while char != new line
    c = getchar();      // get char
    if(c == ' '){        //if char equal space
        c = '\0';    //make c equal end of line
        msg[length] = c;    //add c to the end of line
        strcpy(*command, msg);  //copy the word into the first part of the array
        command++; //increase command array
    }
    else{                           //if word does not equal space
        msg[length] = c;       //add char to the msg
        length++;             //increase length by one
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You've allocated no space for your msg string.

Comment: It's been a while since I've used C. 
   `char* msg = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char) * 30);`
?

Comment: Alright, check. Allocated enough space. Still getting a segFault

Comment: @user2808307 `malloc returns void pointer`. that can be assigned to any pointer. so you need not to cast.see [Do I cast the result of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) and sizeof(char) is 1. you can avoid multiplying with 1.

Answer (score 0):

You have not Allocated memory for msg pointer and you need make length value Zero when space occurs

```
char *msg = ""; //declare static array or allocate some space As below
char msg[MAX_SIZE+1];  or char *msg=malloc(MAX_SIZE+1);
```

Modify your code

```
   i=length=0;   

   while(((c = getchar())!='\n') && (i != 10)){       //read here and check here it self  

        if(c == ' '){
            msg[length] = '\0';        //instead of storing null in char and then in string directly store null in string
            strcpy(command[i++], msg); //use commands pointer array   
            length=0;                  //you should make this zero when space occurs
                   }  

        else                        
            msg[length++] = c;         //if not space copy into string

       }       

    commands[i]=NULL;                  //this tells you how many words you have in the given line.
```

Also check with commands pointer array memory allocation. each pointer must have enough space to store msg string.

Comment: Make `c` an `int` and try `while (((c = getchar()) != '\n') && (c != EOF) && (i < 10) {` to check for EOF, and because the last valid index for `command` is 9 not 10..

Comment: making `c an int is indeed because of getchar() returns int`.  and checkinh for EOF is also Nice idea. `i!=10 is same as i<10` when i becomes 10 at that moment loop fails.

Comment: Oops... I should've noticed that (`i < 10` vs. `i != 10`)... yes, either is fine.